# Collecting data from disparate excel workbooks into a single workbook

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, dialog

I have a main workbook with some code in it.  That code opens hundreds (and eventually potentially thousands) of excel workbooks.  It extracts data from each of those external workbooks and saves that information to various spreadsheets in the main workbook.

The program works - and has worked. However - and I'm not sure whether this is due to a code change or to more data - the program produces, after working for more than 100 files, a modal dialog box for each successive file that reads "This workbook contains links to other data sources" and insists that I click "Update", "Don't update" or "Help."  I now have to click "don't update" 100s of times through this helpful message.

I have tried Application.DisplayAlerts=false
It doesn't help.  Still get the helpful message in a model dialog box after processing a few hundred files.

Unable to locate the Application.OverrideEveryStupidDefaultMSEverThoughtOf property.

Is there a way to solve or circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that quite a few messages appear even though `DisplayAlerts` is set to `False`. After reading your question and feeling curious about this, I did a quick research and found various properties avoiding different types of messages. And yes, yours has also its own property ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194812.aspx)):

```
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
```

Answer (score 2):

Your simple question looks complicated because you didn't show any code you use. If there is any code I think almost half of supporters would help you 5 minutes after your question appeared.

However, I could only guess that somewhere in your code you have this tiny instruction:

```
Workbooks.Open ...
```

if so, this `.Open method` has a special parameter which will solve your problem. [Here is MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194819%28v=office.14%29.aspx) with some explanation. What you should use is second parameter `UpdateLinks` which you should set to either `True` of `False` in this way:

```
Workbooks.Open filePath+fileName, True ' to update links
Workbooks.Open filePath+fileName, False ' to not update links
```